# Как обратиться к данным модели из QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

В QtQuick.Controls 1.4 есть ComboBox, а в нём есть свойство textRole, которое задаёт роль, извлекаемую из модели для отображения в выпадающем списке. Аналогично этому примеру я создал свойство dataRole, но не знаю, как, имея текстовое название роли, извлечь из модели соответствующие данные. Например,

```
property string dataRole: "number"
text: model.number //Так работает
text: model.dataRole //А так не работает
```

Пробовал пользоваться методом data:

```
text: model.data(index, roleNumber)
```

но здесь требуется номер роли, а не текстовое название. Получить номер по текстовому названию в QML не могу, так как метод `getRoleNames` не помечен как `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Как подобное реализовано со свойством `textRole`?

---

UPD. Скорее всего, этот код работал бы как надо, если бы метод `property` был помечен как `Q_INVOKABLE`.

```
ComboBox {
        currentIndex: 2
        model: ListModel {
            id: cbItems
            ListElement { text: "Banana"; color: "Yellow"; data: "1"}
            ListElement { text: "Apple"; color: "Green"; data: "2"}
            ListElement { text: "Coconut"; color: "Brown";  data: "3"}
        }
        textRole: "text" // Роль "text" используется внутри ComboBox для извлечения данных, отображаемых в выпадающем списке
        property string dataRole: "data" //Эту роль надо вывести в лог
        width: 200
        onCurrentIndexChanged: console.debug(cbItems.get(currentIndex).text +
                               ", " + cbItems.get(currentIndex).color +
                               ", " + cbItems.get(currentIndex).property(dataRole))
    }
```

p.s. До рабочего компьютера доберусь только в понедельник.

---

UPD2.

Вот так работает как надо, однако надо будет проверить на рабочем проекте, так как там в качестве модели используется `QAbstractListModel`.

```
ComboBox {
        currentIndex: 2
        model: ListModel {
            id: cbItems
            ListElement { text: "Banana"; color: "Yellow"; data: "1"}
            ListElement { text: "Apple"; color: "Green"; data: "2"}
            ListElement { text: "Coconut"; color: "Brown";  data: "3"}
        }
        textRole: "text"
        property string dataRole: "data"
        width: 200
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            console.debug(cbItems.get(currentIndex)[dataRole])
        }
    }
```

---

UPD3. Нет, в случае с `QAbstractListModel` такой подход не работает. Там нет метода `get`.

```
ChannelTypeModel {
    id: channelTypeModel
}

ComboBox {
    id: channelTypeSelector
    model: channelTypeModel
    textRole: "text"
    property string dataRole: "number"
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        console.log(model.data(model.index(currentIndex, 0), 257))
    }
}
```

Comment: Честно говоря не понял что вы хотите

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко, Имея текстовое название роли (`dataRole = "number"`), извлечь данные из модели по этой роли.

Comment: То есть сделать то же самое, что делает ComboBox при работе со свойством textRole.

Comment: можно ваш полный код?

Comment: вы про это http://pastebin.com/4fFPXJyy ?

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Не пойму зачем вы примешиваете сюда "Q_INVOKABLE", который нужен только лишь, чтобы добавить в область видимости метод из С++ слоя, причём здесь qml?

Comment: `TypeError: Property 'property' of object QObject(0x34c92a88) is not a function` - вот что выдал ваш код

Comment: И всё же я не понимаю что конкретно вы хотите, мб этот код вам даст что-то понять, он показывает какие методы существуют в cb https://goo.gl/5Jg88F